# Selenium Javascript won't retrieve value

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dom, selenium

I'm writing a webpage that uses the Selenium WebDriver to retrieve the contents of an input on another page.

This is the input field on the page I want to retrieve info from:

```
<input id="ReviewProposal_OwnerName" name="ReviewProposal.OwnerName" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="" />
```

This is the script that assigns the input on the page I want to retrieve info from:

```
$('#ReviewProposal_OwnerName').val(data.Owner1);
```

To retrieve the value, I wrote, after navigating to the page with my driver:

```
 IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

IWebElement nameOfOwnerField = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ReviewProposal_OwnerName"));

string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return $('#ReviewProposal_OwnerName').val();");
output.InnerText += title;
```

The output is a div on the page I wrote.

Yet even though text is displayed in the input field on the page, when I try to retrieve it through my code, I always get an empty string. If I look at the input field in firebug, the text is displayed in the browser even if the value in the debugger is marked as blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, didn't work with webdriver yet a lot, but have you try `string title = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ReviewProposal_OwnerName")).GetAttribute("value");` instead of using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because your input is readonly and jQuery just can't set its value.